# Mesh Shrinks when extruding downwards

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap

im fairly new to blender and im attempting to create a raised web pattern on my model when i encountered this thing happening on my web.

as you can see here this is where i start moving downwards into where the mouth is supposed to be.
[image]

but when i extrude the web it starts getting more narrow.
[image]
these are my modifiers on the web mesh

[image]
[image]

help would be appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Can you provide the file? (Use Blend Exchange .Follow the instructions on the site and paste the link)

Comment: @TheKalaakaar the file is on the post now.